# Duplicating a column and placing right next to that duplicated column

Tags: r, copy, columnsorting

I want to duplicate a column, but all the examples I see has the duplicated column go right at the end of the data frame, but I want it right next to what was duplicated instead, and push the rest of the data down instead.

For example: I have DF1

| Name | Key | BCD12A | ACA1 | DEX2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X_1_group1 | test1234 | 10 | 10 | 8 |
| X_2_group1 | test4553 | 8 | 7 | 4 |
| X_2_group2 | test3341 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| X_2_group1 | test2142 | 5 | 6 | 8 |
| X_1_group2 | test4722 | 6 | 7 | 4 |

Duplicating this, I would have another column that copies"DF$Key" right after the second column. Any suggestions on doing this would be appreciated!

```
# DF1
Name <- c("X_1_group1", "X_2_group1", "X_2_group2", "X_2_group1", "X1_group2")
Key <- c("test1234", "test4553", "test3341", "test2142", "test4722")
BCD12A <- c(10, 8, 5, 5, 6)
ACA1 <- c(10, 7, 5, 6, 7)
DEX2 <- c(8, 4, 5, 8, 4)
DF1 <- data.frame(Name, Key, BCD12A, ACA1, DEX2)
```

Comment: Isn't the last one `"X_1_group2"` instead of `"X1_group2"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may use `mutate` with `.after` or `.before` to create the column.  The input to `.after/.before` can be either unquoted/quoted column name or numeric column index

```
library(dplyr)
DF1 <- DF1 %>% 
     mutate(Key2 = Key, .after = Key)
```

-output

```
DF1
        Name      Key     Key2 BCD12A ACA1 DEX2
1 X_1_group1 test1234 test1234     10   10    8
2 X_2_group1 test4553 test4553      8    7    4
3 X_2_group2 test3341 test3341      5    5    5
4 X_2_group1 test2142 test2142      5    6    8
5 X_1_group2 test4722 test4722      6    7    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R version:

```
DF1$Key2 <- DF1$Key
col_order <- c(1:2, 6, 3:5)
DF1[, col_order]
```

```
        Name      Key     Key2 BCD12A ACA1 DEX2
1 X_1_group1 test1234 test1234     10   10    8
2 X_2_group1 test4553 test4553      8    7    4
3 X_2_group2 test3341 test3341      5    5    5
4 X_2_group1 test2142 test2142      5    6    8
5  X1_group2 test4722 test4722      6    7    4
```